# Setting dynamic watermark in to the video using ffmpeg Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-watermarking

I am using this command to overlay the image into the video.

```
ffmpeg",i", inputVideoPath,"-i", imageToOverlay,"
-filter_complex",overlay=10:10","-strict", "-2","-b:a" ,"32k",
"-r","15","-preset", "ultrafast",outputVideoPath
```

Can we set the dynamic values into the "overlay=x:y" also "imageToOverlay" which is image path?

Comment: Yes, you can have a moving overlay. See [here](http://superuser.com/a/1049993/114058).

Comment: @Mulvya I already achieved moving overlay on video but only with static values

Comment: So, you wish to alter the expression during execution? Not possible, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

try this command

```
 //  test with watermark.png 128x128, add it to /sdcard/videokit/
String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg","-y" ,"-i", "/sdcard/videokit/in.mp4","-strict","experimental", "-vf", "movie=/sdcard/videokit/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]","-s", "320x240","-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4","-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "/sdcard/videokit/out.mp4"};
```

for more information check [this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html) link

check [this](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android) link as well

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918907/how-to-add-transparent-watermark-in-center-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg

Comment: i have only used this library for images in php.. but i found a link related to android and i saved it.. and i just share it with you.but i hope above commented link will help you

Comment: yes its working but only for the specific position of watermark, I just need to put watermark on my dynamic x and y positions of array.

Comment: can you sahre the screenshot where it is adding watermark